# Redirect using htaccess for 404 errors

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have the following in my htaccess file for 404 redirects

```
ErrorDocument 404     /index.html
```

So as you can see, if someone hits a non-existing URL like

```
http://example.com/NonExistingFolder/nonExisting.html
```

While this does redirect to my index.html located in the root level,
it cannot locate css, js files referred in index.html
since it attempts to find those under **NonExistingFolder**

How do I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a normal behaviour since you're certainly using *relative* paths for all your resources (images, css, js, href links, etc).

To solve this "issue", you have to use **absolute** paths instead.

One way would be to replace all your relative links by absolute links.
Example (for css):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Note the leading slash which means `path is starting at root level`.

Another solution is to add `<base href="/">` in all your pages right after `<head>` html tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly disable path info then you must use in your .htacceess file:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```